# <audio><source> and <embed> links not working in IE using a dynamic ASPX source

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, audio, embed

I'm trying to play mp3 sound on a webpage, the sound is stored in a SQL database as mp3, so  is returned as a byte[] by a Service method.

My problem is that in Chrome this work fine, but in IE it doesn't, as soon as I start to use the ASPX URL as the source then i.e. balks at playing the sound. I have also tried  with a little more success but not with a dynamic URL. Am I missing something obvious or is this just IE being difficult. While debugging I find that IE does not even attempt to call this URL it's as tho it has decided that it doesnt like the the URL. Any help much appreciated.

1. The `<audio><source>`  method

Method i. (does NOT work in IE)

```
    <audio controls="controls" >
      <source src="PlayAudio.aspx?AudioId=AUDIO00253" />
      Sound Not Supported
    </audio>
```

Method ii. (does NOT work in IE)

```
    <audio controls="controls" >
      <source src="Cyclone.mp3" />
      Sound Not Supported
     </audio>
```

1. The `<embed>` method

Method i. (Does NOT work in IE)

```
   <embed  src="PlayAudio.aspx?AudioId=AUDIO00253" autostart="true" ></embed>
```

Method ii. (DOES work in IE)

```
   <embed  src="Cyclone.mp3" autostart="true"></embed>
```

All four of these methods work fine in Chrome

ASPX method to supply the mp3 byte stream, I know this works fine as it works in Chrome.

```
  private void SendAudio( byte[] audio )
  {
    // Stream byte array to memory stream
    var memStream = new MemoryStream( audio );

    // Write memory stream to response
    Response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
    memStream.WriteTo( Response.OutputStream );
    memStream.Close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the `<audio>` & `<source>` tags are new in HTML 5 which is not supported by IE so they will not work in Internet Explorer (They should work fine in FireFox 4+, Chrome 3+, Safari 4+, Opera 9+, and any other HTML 5 enabled browser.)

Second your code is correct for your method however I have had issues in the past with . I believe the src attribute for the `<embed>` tag requires an actual sound file not a script to execute.

Right now the browser is trying to play your script which it can't. Since your sound data is stored in a database, on the page with the `<embed>` tag you would need to create a temp file to write the data to then call that temp file in the `<embed>` tag.

I am not a total pro at ASPX but I will try to look into it for you.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck with this for a moment. Here, embed also didn't work with **.aspx** or **.ashx** files on IE, **but it did work with classic .asp** . Probably there is some kind of validation on the extension. You can add .asp files to modern asp.net visual studio projects.